# Expected behavior or truncated/overflow cast

Tags: sql, database-agnostic

Is there a standard way for how the following statements evaluate, or is it implementation-defined?

```
SELECT CAST(100000 AS int16);        # integer overflow
SELECT CAST("hello" AS VARCHAR(2));  # string overflow (truncation?)
```

For example, should the number get the max 16-bit value? Raise an error (and if so, why?) Should the string just chop off the first two chars? etc.

Comment: I'm curious, what problem are you trying to solve by asking this?

Comment: Of course it's implementation defined. On Microsoft SQL Server, for example, `SELECT CAST(100000 AS int16);` returns the error message, `Type int16 is not a defined system type.`

Comment: Instead of asking for general answers, which in SQL are hard to come by, ask for the most standard approach for a given RDBMS. This helps focus the problem.

Comment: @DaleK I see, ok I'll change to that.

Comment: @squillman parsing a SQL grammar (for no particular database)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning for SQL server it would be: `[HY019] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The conversion of the varchar value '100000' overflowed an INT2 column. Use a larger integer column`

Comment: @David542 I guess you've found a client driver variation on the error message. The error I quoted was produced via SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning sure but yours is jus saying `int16` isn't a valid type -- the typename is `smallint` in sqlserver (which I assume is echoed back as `int2`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select cast(100000 as smallint) ...` is expected to raise a numeric value out range exception. (`smallint` is ANSI/ISO SQL data type, which I'd consider database agnostic.)

`select cast('hello' as varchar(2)) ...` will give you `'he'`.

Note that character data truncation is treated differently depending on if you read/select, or write/insert.

`select 'hello' into :chr2 ...`, where chr2 is a 2 character target, will give `'he'`, and a string data truncation *warning*.

Bit if you try to INSERT the value `'hello'` into a varchar(2) column, you will get truncation *error*, and no value is inserted.